# Don't stretch one item in CSS Flex box with complex layout

Tags: css, stylesheet, flexbox

I'm trying to create a nested flex box layout that stretches all columns properly (vertically). It seems to work pretty well, except for stretching of one item inside a the nested layout.

```
|---------------------------------------------|
|Header                                       |
|---------------------------------------------|
||--------------------------------|----------||
||TITLE IS THE ISSUE!             |Right     ||
||--------------------------------|Aside     ||
||Left    |Content                |          ||
||Aside   |                       |          ||
||        |                       |          ||
||        |                       |          ||
||        |                       |          ||
||--------|-----------------------|----------||
|---------------------------------------------|
|Footer                                       |
|---------------------------------------------|
```

The problem I'm having is that if the Right Aside gets longer than the other content, the Header stretches vertically. If I try to override the Title align-self attribute to stop it from stretching nothing happens.

A plunker that clearly shows the issue. Look at the gray area (Title - must not grow): http://plnkr.co/edit/9VBSOKi0ipAy1QDpNAKb?p=preview

Thanks...

Answer (score 14):

## From scratch — building the layout from the inside out

There are 3 nested flex containers in this layout.

### #1 - The two inner columns

[image: Columns flex parent]

These columns are wrapped in their own flex parent called `.flex-inner-columns`. The `<main>` element could be a good choice for this parent.

#### The HTML

```
<main class="flex-inner-columns">

  <div class="column-left">
    column-left
  </div>

  <div class="column-right">
    column-right
  </div>

</main>
```

#### The CSS

```
.flex-inner-columns {
  display: flex;
}    
.column-left {
  flex: 1;
 }
.column-right {
  flex: 2;
 }
```

### #2 - Adding the title

[image: Title and column flex parent]

The title and the inner columns parent are encased in another flex parent called `.flex-inner`. The `<section>` element could be a good choice for this parent.

#### The HTML

```
<section class="flex-inner">

  <header class="inner-title">
    <h1>inner-title</h1>
  </header>

  <main class="flex-inner-columns">

    <!-- columns are here -->

  </main>

</section>
```

#### The CSS

The flex-direction for this flex parent is set to `column`. The title is given `flex: 0 1 150px` and will not grow but will shrink from it's default height of 150px if needed. The columns flex container is given `flex: 1` so it will grow and shrink.

```
.flex-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex: 2;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.inner-title {
  flex: 0 1 150px;
  width: 100%;
}
.flex-inner-columns {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1; /* the inner columns flex parent is now given flex 1*/
}
```

### #3 - The final layout — adding the outer flex parent

[image: Final layout flex outer parent]

Everything is wrapped in one final outer container that controls the right aside column. The `.flex-inner` is given `flex: 2` and the `.outer-right` aside is given `flex: 1`.

#### The complete example

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.top-header,
footer {
  height: 10vh;
  background: #E91E63;
}
.flex-outer {
  display: flex;
  height: 80vh;
}
.outer-right {
  flex: 1;
  background: #F48FB1;
}
.flex-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex: 2;
  background: #333;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.inner-title {
  background: #9C27B0;
  flex: 0 1 150px;
  align-self: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.flex-inner-columns {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
.column-left {
  flex: 1;
  background: #CE93D8;
}
.column-right {
  flex: 2;
  background: #AB47BC;
}
```

```html
<header class="top-header">Header</header>
<div class="flex-outer">

  <section class="flex-inner">

    <header class="inner-title">
      <h1>inner-title</h1>
    </header>

    <main class="flex-inner-columns">

      <div class="column-left">
        column-left
      </div>

      <div class="column-right">
        column-right
      </div>

    </main>

  </section>


  <aside class="outer-right">
    right outer
  </aside>

</div>

<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: Beautiful example. Currently I'm searching for examples that show complex layout using flexbox. Thank you misterManSam for your time building this answer, which was definitely underrated, such is life.

PS: If somebody knows where I can find more advances examples of this kind, thanks in advance for give me some links.